# Removing some hostile creatures in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to remove some of the enemies that spawn during the night but retaining some? I actually like playing on a non-peaceful mode but I don't like those creatures *(enderman, creeper)* that can destroy my structures and other *works of art* while still retaining some threats during the night and cave exploration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some mods that can do that, for example http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/631622-endermen-dont-pick-up-blocks-mod/. I remember there was somewhere mod for creepers too.

Comment: Additionally, if you're running a Bukkit server (and perhaps some other servers), there are plugins for things like preventing creepers from breaking blocks when they explode (but still deal damage)

Answer (score 9):

An option since Minecraft 1.4 (snapshot [12w34b](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Development_versions#12w34b), to be precise)  is to turn off mobs' ability to destroy blocks. If you have cheats enabled in single player or OP privilege in multiplayer you can type

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

Creepers and Endermen will still spawn and Creepers will still explode, but they won't be able to destroy blocks. This option is saved in the world file so you only need to type it once for a given save/server.

Answer (score 0):

These other answers are better, but there is another solution, you can run this command (it fits in chat so you don't need a command block) it's:

> /kill @e[type=(Entity)]

but this is not permanent because mobs always are spawning, so you have 2 options:

1. use cheats, make a command block loop with this command
2. use it whenever you feel your house is gonna get rekt
3. use these other answers

Answer (score -2):

You just have to use this command: `/gamerule mobGriefing false`

But you have to have cheats enabled in your world. This will stop endermen from grieving your houses too.

Comment: Hi emma, welcome to Arqade! Please take a moment to read our [help tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) for a short summary of rules of the site. Specifically, please don't repeat an answer that was already given by another user, but rather upvote the existing one. Thanks!