# Is there a way to "turn off" creepers in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this feeling from dealing with the files beforehand that there is some way to turn creepers off, the same way I can mess around with the way some modpacks work. Is there some way I can for instance turn creeper spawn rate to zero or something? That would be lovely.

This is NOT a duplicate of the "how to stop creepers blow stuff up" questions. I asked how to make them disappear, and finally figured it out, using /gamerule domobspawn false to disable all mobs from spawning.

Comment: Related - [How Can I Stop Creepers Destroying Blocks On Minecraft](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102548/how-can-i-stop-creepers-destroying-blocks-on-minecraft)

Comment: One solution would be to turn `mobGriefing` to `false`, using the command `/gamerule mobGriefing false`. This will prevent creeper explosions from damaging blocks, but they still hurt players and it also keeps ghasts, whithers, and endermen from damaging blocks. More information on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97883/what-are-all-the-gamerule-commands-in-minecraft). This will **not** keep creepers from spawning though, it just keeps them from breaking things.

Comment: @fredley I believe that this question should have a different answer than that question. There, the asker states that disabling creepers entirely is *not* a solution, while here it is the only solution. The idea here is to find out if creepers can be kept from spawning, but I thought that gamerules were a good thing to mention in any case, hence my comment above.

Comment: The core problem is the breakage of blocks, that's true, but for my own health's sake, creepers are still the most annoying and to some extent terrifying mob in the overworld. It will probably get better by turning off mobGriefing, though. Thanks. Perhaps now I can build enough to brighten up my town to keep those pesky vermin out without them blowing up everything I own.

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate of disabling block damage, but it is a duplicate of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82541/removing-some-hostile-creatures-in-minecraft)

Comment: Ah, I see.Thank you. Nobody did link me what it was a duplicate of. But yours doesn't have a straight answer for the question either. Although I do agree that is is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always play on Peaceful, which removes all hostile mobs from the game.

To remove just creepers, however, would require a mod of one kind or another.

Some of the links provided in the comments should help you out if that's your case.  But if you just want to remove the 'hostile mobs' problem entirely, playing on peaceful is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I mostly do that. Peaceful is my solution to just about anything, but it would be nice to play normally, just ditching those wandering dynamites. Especially hunger I would like to encounter without having to fight them. It adds such a nice feeling to the game, but those creepers really aren't worth it.